# convertir Date a Calendar en Java

Tags: java, mysql, date

mi pregunta es como puedo obtener un Calendar (FechaNacimiento de una consulta de Mysql a java, lo tengo con

```
resultado.getDate(columnFile, null);
```

pero me dice que

> no se puede convertir (getDate(columnFile, Cal)).

Me dice que Date no se puede convertir a Calendar. Pero lo que yo quiero es obtener la fecha de nacimiento de la Base de Datos e insertarla en el constructor parametrizado.

```
private void buscarDNI(String buscarDni) {
    try {
        sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
        String consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios;";
        ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(consulta);
        usuario = null;
        while (resultado.next()) {
           /* String nombre, String apellidos, int telefono, Calendar fechaNacimiento, 
        String domicilio, String ciudad, String dni, char bloqueado, String usuario,
        String contrasena, char tipo*/
            if (resultado.getString(8).equals(buscarDni)) {
                usuario = new Usuario(resultado.getString(2), resultado.getString(3),
                resultado.getInt(4), resultado.getDate(5, null), resultado.getString(6),
                resultado.getString(7), resultado.getString(8), resultado.getString(9).charAt(0),
                resultado.getString(10), resultado.getString(11), resultado.getString(12).charAt(0));
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Usuario no encontrado.");
            }
        }
        resultado.close();
    } catch(SQLException sql) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR EN LA CONSULTA\n" + sql.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "ERROR AL BUSCAR EL DNI INTRODUCIDO");
    }
```

Clase Usuario:

```
public Usuario(String nombre, String apellidos, int telefono, Calendar fechaNacimiento, 
        String domicilio, String ciudad, String dni, char bloqueado, String usuario,
        String contrasena, char tipo) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    this.domicilio = domicilio;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.bloqueado = bloqueado;
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.contrasena = contrasena;
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar permite usar una funcion setDate para asignar la fecha.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(resultado.getDate(5, null));
```

En tu caso quedaría:

```
if (resultado.getString(8).equals(buscarDni)) {

    // Calculo el calendar primero
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(resultado.getDate(5, null));
    usuario = new Usuario(resultado.getString(2), resultado.getString(3),
                resultado.getInt(4), cal, resultado.getString(6),
                resultado.getString(7), resultado.getString(8), resultado.getString(9).charAt(0),
                resultado.getString(10), resultado.getString(11), resultado.getString(12).charAt(0));

}else ....
```

[Fuente](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime(java.util.Date))

PD: Tu codigo es poco eficiente, no tiene sentido traerte todos los usuarios para luego ir comprobando uno a uno si es el buscado. Lo suyo es filtrar directamente en la consulta.

Comment: No los compruebo uno a uno, solamente compruebo un dato, si esta creo directamente el nuevo objeto tipo usuario para guardar los datos.

Comment: No necesitas hacer 2 consultas, lo que tienes que hacer es filtrar en la unica consulta. Date cuenta que como tengas 2000 usuarios vas a hacer 1 consulta e iterar sobre 2000 mientras que filtrando en la consulta es hacer una consulta e iterar sobre 1.

Comment: Si tienes razón, muchas gracias!